# Use matplotlib to draw a mixed graph of polyline and column, but the polyline is not displayed

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is the code I wrote. The legend can be displayed, but the broken line cannot be displayed.
 The result is shown in the figure below.
 How to display the broken line on the histogram, and the value of each point can also be displayed?
 How to realize this image in detail?
 How to make the X axis value larger?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rcParams

config = {
"font.family":'serif',
"font.size": 10,
"mathtext.fontset":'stix',
"font.serif": ['SimSun'],
}
rcParams.update(config)
plt.rc('font',family='Times New Roman')


font1 = {'family' : 'Times New Roman',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 17,
        }

font2 = {'family' : 'Times New Roman',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 11,
         }
font3 = {'family' : 'Times New Roman',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 19,
        }
font4 = {'family' : 'Times New Roman',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 22,
        }

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.set_ylim(0, 3)
ax2.set_ylim(95, 130)

ax1.set_ylabel('$t_{score}$',font3)
ax2.set_ylabel('$node_iNum$',font3)

node = [110,118,121,107,123]
x = np.arange(5)
bar_wigth = 0.45

x_list= ['$node_1$','$node_2$','$node_3$','$node_4$','$node_5$']
ax2.bar(x,node,bar_wigth,color='green',label='$node_iNum$',alpha=0.6, tick_label=x_list)
ax2.set_xticklabels(x_list,font3)

t_score=[0.95,0.47,0.79,1.42,1.11]
quezhi=[1.94,1.94,1.94,1.94,1.94]
l=[i for i in range(5)]

ax2.plot(l, t_score,'r-',label='$t_{th}$')
ax2.plot(l,quezhi,'b--',label='$t_{score}$')
ax2.plot(l,t_score,'ro',l,quezhi,'b^')

for a, b in zip(l, t_score):
    ax2.text(a, b, b, ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10)
for a, b in zip(l, quezhi):
    ax2.text(a, b, b, ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10)
ax2.legend(loc='upper left', prop=font2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Typo? `ax1.plot(l, t_score,'r-',label='$t_{th}$')` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mr. T commented, you seem to be confusing the 1st and 2nd axes. If the second axis is a bar graph, then the rest of the time it is the first axis, isn't it?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.set_ylim(0, 3)
ax2.set_ylim(95, 130)

ax1.set_ylabel('$t_{score}$',font3)
ax2.set_ylabel('$node_iNum$',font3)

node = [110,118,121,107,123]
x = np.arange(5)
bar_wigth = 0.45

x_list= ['$node_1$','$node_2$','$node_3$','$node_4$','$node_5$']
ax2.bar(x,node,bar_wigth,color='green',label='$node_iNum$',alpha=0.6, tick_label=x_list)
ax2.set_xticklabels(x_list,font3)

t_score=[0.95,0.47,0.79,1.42,1.11]
quezhi=[1.94,1.94,1.94,1.94,1.94]
l=[i for i in range(5)]

ax1.plot(l, t_score,'r-', label='$t_{th}$')
ax1.plot(l, quezhi,'b--', label='$t_{score}$')
ax1.plot(l, t_score, 'ro', l, quezhi,'b^')

for a, b in zip(l, t_score):
    ax1.text(a, b, b, ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10)
for a, b in zip(l, quezhi):
    ax1.text(a, b, b, ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=10)

fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), bbox_transform=ax2.transAxes, loc='upper left', prop=font2)

fig.show()
```

[image]